# I don't understand the Definition 2.5 in the Logic for Mathematicians written by A.G.Hamilyon.Please help me

Tags: first-order-logic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37AVS.jpg)Definition 2.5
Let Γ be a set of wfs. of L (which may or may not be axioms or theorems of L). A sequence Al,..., An, of wfs. of L is a deduction from Γ if for each i (1 -< i -< n), one of the following holds:

(a) Ai is an axiom of L,

(b) Ai is a member of Γ, or

(c) Ai follows from two previous members of the sequence as a direct consequence using MP.
So a deduction from Γ is just a 'proof' in which the members of Γ are considered as temporary axioms. The last member, An, of a sequence which is a deduction from Γ is said to be deducible from Γ or to be a consequence of Γ in L.

Above is the original text.
My question comes from the sentence of (a) : Since Ai is an axiom, how did it deduce from Γ, considering that Γ might not be the axiom set?

Comment: The idea is that axioms of $L$ are "for free" - they can't *not* be deducible.

Comment: But the auther says:A sequence A1,..., An, of wfs. of L is a deduction from Γ if for each i (1 ≤ i ≤n)Ai is an axiom of L

Comment: Quoting the author in your comment, you omitted "one of the following holds".

Comment: Thank you.I know what you mean,But I think what the author means is: it is also true in the case of (a).I  send the pictures of the textbook

Comment: The author is defining how the words "deduction" and "deducible" are to be used in his book. Clearly if $\mathcal{A}$ is an axiom there is a one-line deduction $\mathcal{A}$ using case (a) of the definition. And so $\mathcal{A}$ is deducible by the definition of "deducible". You may not like it, but I suspect that you have a private definition of "deducible" lurking in your mind.

Comment: i don't understand how do you deduce an axiom from a set of formulas that may not be the axioms.Because the auther says Γ maynot be the axioms.Such a definition of "deducible" seems like unreasonable